# why Created Date fields is also update on merge records?

Tags: apex, trigger, merge

I'm merging the old existing lead with a new lead. but the problem is in the new lead all Created Date and other information is also getting updated in the new lead. which I don't want can anyone suggest how to avoid this created date field from updating in the new lead while merging.

```
public static void mergeDuplicateLead(List<Lead> newLeadList){
        Map<String,Lead> phoneWithLeadMap = new Map<String,Lead>();
        Lead newLead = [SELECT Phone FROM Lead WHERE Id IN:newLeadList LIMIT 1];
        Set<String> phoneset = new Set<String>();
        for(Lead objLead : newLeadList){
            phoneset.add(objLead.Phone);
        }
        
        for(Lead objExstLead : [select Phone from lead where( Phone IN: phoneset) 
                                AND Id NOT IN : newLeadList) ]){
            phoneWithLeadMap.put(objExstLead.Phone,objExstLead);
                                    
        }
        for(Lead objLead : newLeadList){
            
                if(phoneWithLeadMap.containsKey(objLead.Phone)){
                    Lead exstingLead = phoneWithLeadMap.get(objLead.Phone);
                    merge newLead exstingLead;
                }
            
        }
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep the original dates, aren't you merging the wrong way around?

Comment: Hi Girbot, Actually I'm merging lead only because of I want old lead related list like task in new lead. Another way I've think of update task whoid and then delete old lead but in merge it'll automatically do it's job. And can you suggest another way of achieve this thing?

Answer (score 0):

In the [merge syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm), the first record is the surviving record and the second record is the losing one. In your case, you are using the newer record as the surviving record, so that's where the created date is coming from.

Just swap the statement around: `merge exstingLead newLead;`

Comment: Hii @Daniel I want need lead to survive because new lead details should be there and old lead related list and all details but new lead created date should not change.

Comment: The whole point of the merge is to combined all the related lists on the surviving record. Have you tried your merge in the opposite direction and seen problems?